# pygame. Столкновения

Tags: python, pygame

Нужно, чтобы когда игрок сталкивался с "противником", второй исчезал. Но есть проблема, я прописываю столкновения следующим образом:

```
for e in enem:
        if e.y > 500:
            hp -=0           ## falling           
            if hp <= 0:
                run = False
        if (y <= e.y+30 and e.x== x) or (y <= e.y+30 and e.x== x-1) or...or (y <= e.y+30 and e.x== x+30): 
            enem.pop(enem.index(e))
```

То есть я просто прописываю все возможные координаты на которых они могут встретиться. Как сделать эту операцию более граммотной?

Comment: x и у это координаты игрока соответственно.

Comment: почитайте о `pygame.Rect`